# How to pretty print json objects to db using Node-orm2

Tags: json, node.js, express, pretty-print, node-orm2

I'm using [node-orm2](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2) to persist a model to a mysql db column. It works great, except I want the written json pretty printed, so I can easily read it when I view the DB.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

you can use JSON stringify with params:

```
var obj = {manu: true, gili: "abc"}
var str = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4); // spacing = 4
```

Comment: All whitespaces are removed during save() when the field is of type Object :(. Will only work if field is defined and string and JSON stringify and parse are called after save/load.